# Writing an API that can handle asynchronous and synchronous called methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, portable-class-library

I may not be approaching my problem in the correct fashion so I will explain in some detail what I already have. 

I've written a PCL that essentially represents my Business Layer.  This Business Layer makes calls to several Web Services and wraps internal DTO's in business objects which are then consumed by several presentation layers (WinRT, Android, iOS, and Web Clients).

I would like to cache the results of some of the Web Service calls to "disk" in order to do this I must inject the dependency of each platforms method of serializing data to its own storage.  Enter an interface to do so.

Trouble is though some platforms may only provide synchronous or asynchronous API's to store data to disk.  For example StorageFile in WinRT only has `async/await` TAP based API's.

My question is how can I get these wildly differing components to play nicely.  I'm thinking about creating the interface with asynchronous methods and somehow convert the potential synchronous methods to these pseudo-async entities... but that just doesn't feel right.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You always can call asynchronous method synchronously and vise versa using native asynchronous mechanisms.

Comment: Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). I will suggest you to create an API which takes its own shape; by that I mean if your API is inherently asynchronous expose async version only, user can wait upon it if he needs, and vice versa

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I will read those two links you have posted. The problem is, it is not known whether or not the implementation is inherently asynchronous or synchronous as this is left up to the user of the PCL.  The Web Service wrappers are asynchronous in the PCL so it would be desirable to have the caching/serialization process be asynchronous too (as this promotes expected behaviour of an asynchronous programming interface).

Unfortunately serialization API's exposed by .NET are not asynchronous to date, another cause for concern.  My only option looks to be wrapping with Task.Run

Comment: @roadysix: As a general rule, CPU-bound operations (such as in-memory serialization) are synchronous, and I/O-bound operations (such as web service calls and disk access) are asynchronous.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yeah I read something similar on your blog (big help on getting me up to speed with `async/await`).  What would you suggest for serializing to disk? as it is both CPU-bound and performing IO.

Comment: @roadysix: Assuming the serialization is non-trivial (i.e., you would not want to run it on the UI thread), then you could consider splitting up the CPU-bound portion from the I/O-bound portion. If that isn't feasible, then you should expose an asynchronous API but with comments that make it clear that it *also* has synchronous, CPU-bound parts.

Comment: Hmmm that's a weak-sauce solution, though it would seem it is the only one.  The entire problem I'm having with defining the interface to be asynchronous or synchronous stems from the fact that you cannot substitute the return type with Task/Task<T> when a method is declared `async`.  If it were addressed, no one would ever need to use `async void` and infact using only Task/Task<T> could be enforced.

Comment: I don't see a reason to write (today) any synchronous disk operation (if I have a choice :)